Children are stuck in a dream, together. Parents must save them. Involves marbles in the dead of winter
There was a horror film of some kind that my parents watched on VHS.
It involved quite a few children who were all stuck in some sort of coma. I believe the children themselves could interact with one another in their dream state. I remember it was up to the parents to save them based on a task. Unfortunately, some of the parents failed and thus the ontological being killed their offspring.
I remember this movie takes place in a winter cabin and revolved around the use of marbles. If anyone has an idea, that would be great!

I think it might be Stephen King's Storm of the Century, (1999).

A very powerful blizzard hits the fictional small town of Little Tall Island 
  (also the setting of King's novel Dolores Claiborne) off the coast of
  Maine. The storm is so powerful that all access off the island is
  blocked, and no one is able to leave the island until the storm is
  over.
...
Linoge's campaign of terror culminates
  in an enchantment that places all eight of the town's small children
  into unconsciousness. He eventually calls a town meeting, and it is
  here that Linoge reveals the reason why he has come into their town.
What Linoge desires is an heir, one of the eight children he has
  enchanted.
...
Although Michael Anderson begs the town to refuse Linoge's request, appealing 
  to their common decency and the fact that they may be aiding in a
  great evil, his arguments fall on deaf ears. All of the townspeople
  except him vote to give Linoge what he desires. Linoge is deeply
  pleased at this choice, and has each parent draw one
  of eight "weirding stones" from a sack; seven white stones, and one
  black stone. The parent who draws the single black stone is the one
  whose child will be taken.

The "weirding stones" look like marbles.  I remember the unconscious children dream they are flying together with Linoge.

I do remember the white weirding stone! Finding this movie has been bothering me for years! Thank you!
